# App running on Unicorn@Heroku behaves differently than running on Webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, unicorn, webrick

I just switched from Webrick to Unicorn on Heroku and got into some problems that I would never dream of.
Customer contacted me that they no longer can do particular actions. I went through logs on Heroku and there were no problems there. However I noticed that there were some memory related problems, but those were solved by downscaling parallel requests on Unicorn. Since that, there were no problems. I ended up downloading the DB and attaching it locally to discover that there is no problem there. 
I tried everything except changing server back to Webrick. 
Totally desperate, I tried even that and IT WORKED! 
Is there any reason why the app is behaving differently? There is no error, Heroku shows no problems.
Simply, the DB transaction won't complete, because there are no data stored in DB.

I cannot run on Webrick indefinitely, because right now it's causing the connection pool to deplete pretty fast and because of that I am forced to restart the server from time to time.

Any help?

Thanks

UPDATE:

This is the content of config/unicorn.rb

```
#config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 2)
timeout 60
preload_app true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead'
    Process.kill 'QUIT', Process.pid
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  Signal.trap 'TERM' do
    puts 'Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT'
  end

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

and this is config/initializers/database_connection.rb

```
#config/initializers/database_connection.rb
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
                Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DB_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
    config['pool'] = ENV['DB_POOL'] || ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

UPDATE 2:

I just tried to fork the application and provision all the resources to replicate the original environment. Everything works properly on forked application. The only difference is that there is no SSL endpoint.
I don't get it.

Comment: "Simply, the DB transaction won't complete, because there are no data stored in DB" this sounds completely unrelated to your choice of web server. Can you explain the problem more, with more concrete examples of what is or is not happening? Check this guide as well https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

Comment: How can this be unrelated. The only difference between storing and not storing the data is switching to Unicorn from Webrick.

Comment: Are you doing anything to handle ActiveRecord connections during the unicorn fork?

Comment: Just what's suggested at Heroku's documentation. I updated my question with contents of config/unicorn.rb and config/initializers/database_connection.rb

Comment: maybe I misinterpreted "because there are no data stored in DB". Have you double checked the DATABASE_URL on your application, to make sure you're trying to store to the correct database? There should be logs in your application that show information on the request.